# Prevent duplicate lists across modules?

Tags: python, list

I'm very new to Python, and this is a very general question. In my situation, it relates to a list, but I believe the same behavior would be observed with any other type.

I have a simple list defined in a module that is imported into several other modules:

```
list = [MyType(0),
    MyType(1),
    MyType(2),
    MyType(3)]
```

**Edit:**

Because of comments by Cireo and Grismar, I believe this is unexpected behavior. And I believe its happening because of the way I'm using the import system. This is what I'm doing at the moment, which I'm only starting to understand how it works:

**__init__.py:**

I don't completely understand why I have to import *all* of the project modules here. But if I remove any, my add-on (in Blender) seams to be missing the module I removed.

```
# import system module
import sys

# import local modules
# only global_module and sub_module are relevant to this example
from . import global_module, sub_module, another_module, some_other
```

**sub_module.py**

```
# import system modules
import bpy

# import local modules
from . import global_module

... access to globals ...
def Function():
    var = global_module.data.x
```

In my project, I would have several modules that work like sub_module.py. Several of them import global_module. global_module does not import anything local, but the list instance would be defined there.

Anyone see any problems with this?

Comment: Try to make a self-contained minimal example. I wouldn't expect any import after the first one to call init

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. If you wouldn't expect it, then I am likely making a mistake during my importing. I'm going to try to figure that out, then I'll post some code if I can't figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: The `__init__()` is called each time an object is instantiated, but the code in the main body of a module should only be executed once. So, if your list declaration is in the main body of a module, that's certainly unexpected, but you'd have to share some code with this problem for us to help spot the issue. By the way, spelling `MyType` with capitals is correct, but spelling the variable `List` with a capital is again best practices. Python coders and some editors will assume `List` is a type.

Comment: Changed it to use lower case. I'm building an add-on in the Blender environment, and have been using an import reloader utility, which may be part of the reason this was happening. It essentially reloads code when there are changes, but I wasn't using it the most intelligent way. That helped tremendously. Got it down to about 3-4 repeated calls, and I think these are caused by me incorrectly using the import system. I'm going to edit the end of the question to reflect your advice.

Comment: Thanks for the updates @Robert, is it possible that your code is generating a pyc when it is loaded, which triggers the import reloader?  If you have control over it, have it just watch the source (.py) files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cireo** and **Grismar** guided me to the answer to this issue. The problem was indeed caused by me using the import system incorrectly. I'm very new at this (and still don't have a solid grasp on the inner workings of importing), so I was accidentally importing the same module files into `__init__.py` multiple times.

After doing some research and studying source code from other add-ons for Blender, I cleaned it up, and now I'm getting what you would expect - one instance of each variable being constructed.

Thanks for the help guys.